# Thank You email after interview?

Tags: interviewing, email, follow-up

My interview went well and I'd like to send a Thank You email.

He said they'd let me know by next week.

It is Friday so should I send a thank you email right now, before their decision next week?

I'm thinking if I DON'T it will make me stand out (in a bad way).

Comment: Aside: I don't know about the US, but in the UK, I don't think it's normal to send a thank you e-mail. I would be a little grossed out if someone sent me one after an interview just as procedural flora.

Answer (score 7):

Sending a thank you email is fine, regardless if they hire you or not.

I typically wait a day then just say give a simple thank you for your time and consideration etc. Keep it short and sweet. Something short enough that when the person opens it they don't feel the need to look at it later when they have more time.

"Thank you for your time and consideration, I hope we'll be working together in the future" Sincerely, Name

That's an example of something I might send.

Comment: what should I put in the subject?